# (Swift) need help swiping between view controllers

Tags: swift, xcode, viewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

These are my view controllers: [image]

I want to make it so that I can swipe between the three of them starting in the middle one. All of the tutorials I've found require you to start from scratch and don't show me how to connect the three I have. Does anyone have a step-by-step instruction of how to do this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Create a class called PageViewController, drag a `UIPageViewController` in storyboard.For now lets set it as initial view controller from attributes inspector. Also from identity inspector set PageViewController as Class.

Call your three view controller for example StepZero,StepOne,StepTwo Also give them identifier in storyboard.

lets deep into coding now, so in PageViewController should subclass `UIPageVIewController`:

```
import UIKit

class PageViewController : UIPageViewController,UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

    var selectedIndex = 1

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        dataSource = self

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()

        // This is the starting point.  Start with step zero.
        setViewControllers([getStepOne()], direction: .Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }

    func getStepZero() -> StepZero {
        return storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("StepZero") as! StepZero
    }

    func getStepOne() -> StepOne {
        return storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("StepOne") as! StepOne
    }

    func getStepTwo() -> StepTwo {
        return storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("StepTwo") as! StepTwo
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if viewController.isKindOfClass(StepTwo) {
            // 2 -> 1
            return getStepOne()
        } else if viewController.isKindOfClass(StepOne) {
            // 1 -> 0
            return getStepZero()
        } else {
            // 0 -> end of the road
            return nil
        }
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if viewController.isKindOfClass(StepZero) {
            // 0 -> 1
            return getStepOne()
        } else if viewController.isKindOfClass(StepOne) {
            // 1 -> 2
            return getStepTwo()
        } else {
            // 2 -> end of the road
            return nil
        }
    }

    // Enables pagination dots
    func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    // This only gets called once, when setViewControllers is called
    func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return selectedIndex
    }


}
```

Let's say in Storyboard you have three viewControllers, you should set identifier for them from identity inspector as StepZero StepOne StepTwo for example and when you instantiate them you do :

```
func getStepZero() -> StepZero {
    return storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("StepZero") as! StepZero
}

func getStepOne() -> StepOne {
    return storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("StepOne") as! StepOne
}

func getStepTwo() -> StepTwo {
    return storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("StepTwo") as! StepTwo
}
```

The selected index is the index you want to start with which is number 1. And to start with second view controller call `getStepOne()` in `setViewControllers`. if you want to start with view controller 3 use selected index 2 and call `getStepTwo()`...etc

Download Updated Sample : https://mega.nz/#!EQEFhbwS!0yoy5RvAliQNnjRevWo05wPWk7P08e8DVetRZdjg-ro

Comment: I'm getting an error: "'Use of undeclared type ViewController'" any solutions for this?

Comment: @evanhaus ViewController is the name of your class. In my sample it's called ViewControlller , maybe in your sample it's called something else !

Comment: Okay cool! One more issue, "MyViewController has no member "pageIndex"

Comment: @evanhaus You can add in your MyViewControlller var pageIndex : Int? Should make the error goes away .

Comment: @Aaoli I tried to load the following after a person signs in: `let mainStoryBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let homeViewController: UIViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageViewController")
        
        self.presentViewController(homeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: @Aaoli but I get this error from this line of code: "self.setViewControllers([pageContentViewController!], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)" is giving me the following error: "warning: could not load any Objective-C class information. This will significantly reduce the quality of type information available." Any idea what that means?

Comment: @evanhaus , please download the updated project. i have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect your view controllers by navigation controller . Just select one of your view controllers -> Editor(on the top bar of mac) -> Embed in -> Navigation controller.

Also if you want to swipe you can use a scroll view and only on view controller . Scroll view with content size of 3 view controllers can help you do the same. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Follow as below image**

[image]

**Give storyboard identifier as shown in below image**

[image]

**On button click push new viewcontroller**

```
var viewControllerObj=self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("your storyboard identifier") 
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(viewControllerObj, animated: true)
```